# What does this pointer do in the argument of this function?

Tags: c, pointers

I am an electronics guy so, treat me well, please.

I was reading [this](http://eetimes.com/design/embedded/4008325/FLIRTing-with-8-bit-MCU-OSes?pageNumber=0) article about real time operating systems for 8-bit microcontrollers. I came across this function with a weird looking argument. I could not understand what it is doing. I know that `void` means "no type". I am guessing that `(*Task)` is the casting. I really have no idea what those brackets do after that.

What does this function's argument include?

Also, I couldn't understand what does `*(int*)((NewTCB->Stack) + (STACK_DEPTH-2)) = (int)Task;` do?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text; post the text itself.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am sorry, I was afraid I would make errors converting it to the text, and also I thought it was reasonably readable (but not findable by Google).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void (*Task)()` is actually a **function pointer**. Basically it is saying: "the parameter name is `Task` and it is a function which returns `void` and (since this is c not c++) takes any number of arguments.

So you could call it like this:

```
void my_task() {
    /* do something */
}

TaskCreate(my_task);
```

Of course, it would also be safe to write `void my_task(void) {` as well. When coding c, I personally prefer to explicitly say "there are no parameters"

Finally, `*(int*)((NewTCB->Stack) + (STACK_DEPTH-2)) = (int)Task;` is doing some casting magic.

Let's disect it:

`(int)Task` is first converting `Task` to an `int` (which is questionable, but probably ok for your particular architecture/OS. Personally, I would use a `long` to be safe).

`((NewTCB->Stack) + (STACK_DEPTH-2))` is just doing some simple arithmetic on `NewTCB->Stack` to get a pointer to a location in the `TCB`'s stack.

`*(int*)` says "convert this to an `int *` and then deference (read or write) the location it points to.

We could write this more simply as follows:

```
int f = (int)Task;
int s = ((NewTCB->Stack) + (STACK_DEPTH-2)); /* I don't know the type of `NewTCB->Stack`, so we'll pretend 'int' for now */
int *stack_ptr = (int*)s;
*stack_ptr = f;
```

which is probably more clear.

**FOLLOW UP**: I'd like to point out how I use tend to use function pointers since the syntax can be a bit confusing sometimes. And I find this approach to be very helpful. Basically I like to create a `typedef` for the function pointer and use that instead, I find it a lot easier to get right:

For example:

```
/* typedef func_t to be a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning void */
typedef void (*func_t)(void);
```

Then later...

```
void CreateTask(func_t task) {
    /* same work as your example, just a little easier to read */
}
```

Comment: Wow, stackoverflow SE is great! 3 answers in ~5 mins? Wow! Wish we had it in electronics SE.

Comment: Not yet read the whole answer, but is `void (*task)()` same as `void *(task)()` ?

Comment: **no**, `void *(task)()` is a function named `task` which return a `void*` (pointer to arbitrary type)

Comment: @EvanTeran you may want to correct your answer. You say `void *(task)()` right at the beginning.

Comment: @Johannes: good catch, that's what I get for trying to get my answers out fast :-P

Comment: `Personally, I would use a long to be safe.` Well, in the 8-bit world, one may not be able to afford that `long`, lol.

Comment: @abdullah kahraman: completely reasonable, if you know `int` to be safe, then it is fine. At this level of code, you need to make architecture specific choices that best suite your needs :-).

Comment: That is what I love about 8-bit microcontrollers. And yes, I am an engineer, I love making choices :)

Answer (score 0):

`*(int*)((NewTCB->Stack) + (STACK_DEPTH-2)) = (int)Task;` takes `Task` and converts it to an integer.  Then, it finds `NewTCB`'s stack (some form of an array).  It takes that stack and finds the penultimate member.  It then treats that as the address of an integer variable and assigns the converted Task to the variable at that address.

`NewTCB->stack` uses C++ pointer-to-member syntax.  `NewTCB` is a pointer to a `TCB` object, and `TCB` objects evidently have a Stack property.
Adding `STACK_DEPTH - 2` to it is the same as writing `(NewTCB->Stack)[STACK_DEPTH - 2]` (in plaintext: `NewTCB->Stack`: get object at index `STACK_DEPTH - 2`) except that the stack object is a dynamically assigned array.
If `NewTCB->Stack` has length `STACK_DEPTH`, then the object at index `STACK_DEPTH - 2` is the penultimate member (0-based indices).
The rest just handles conversions necessary to move Task to the appropriate spot.

Comment: `NewTCB->stack` is not a C++ feature. It is **exactly** the same as `(*NewTCB).stack`

Comment: Right, but C does not support objects.  That's all I meant.

Comment: it supports `struct`s though. `struct T { int n; };` struct T *x = malloc(sizeof(struct T)); x->n = 10;` completely valid c.

Answer (score 0):

Evan Teran's answer is correct. I'd expand on it by saying that from the code it seems to be a pointer to the function that's executed when the task is selected to be run.

As for `*(int*)((NewTCB->Stack) + (STACK_DEPTH-2)) = (int)Task;`

I assume in your environment `int` is 16 bits? If so this would be the -2. This code saves the address of the Task's 'main' function in this structure (which is weird because it's already saved in the `->Task` member, but there's probably a good reason)